# how to copy ElasticSearch field to another field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 100GB ES index now. Right now I need to change one field to multi-fields, such as: `username` to `username.username` and `username.raw` (`not_analyzed`). I know it will apply to the incoming data. But how can I make this change affect on the old data? Should I using index scroll to copy the whole index to a new one, Or there is a better solution to just copy one filed please.

Comment: You need to reindex all the documents in that index. Create a new index and re-index everything there or drop the current index and re-create it from scratch with the new mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a way to achieve this **without reindexing** all your data by using the [update by query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery).

Basically, after installing the plugin, you can run the following query and all your documents will get the multi-field re-populated.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/your_index/_update_by_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "script" : "ctx._source.username = ctx._source.username;"
}'
```

It might take a while to run on 100GB docs, but after this runs, the `username.raw` field will be populated.

Note: for this plugin to work, one needs to have [scripting enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).

Comment: And don't you think this will put a bit of pressure on the cluster, by allowing a very large number of deleted documents in the segments? Depending on the merging behavior one could end up having a high number of deleted documents in a single segment, thus taking both space on disk and, also, affecting (in some scenario might be relevant) the search performance.

Comment: Definitely agree. Though, if this partial re-indexing is wisely combined with some after-the-fact re-optimization, the segments with deleted documents should get eliminated. Also worth noting that full re-indexing in the same index would have the same effect. In the end, my guts tell me that update by query + optimization would take less time than re-creating the index from scratch, but that's just me based on some past experiences doing the same thing.

Comment: The optimization would have to be with max_num_segments=1. 100 GB docs would take a bit of time to optimize. In my opinion, deleting the index and recreating it (of course, if the data is stored somewhere else and the the re-indexing is possible from that place) would definitely take  less time than updating every document and then optimize.

Answer (score 0):

POST index/type/_update_by_query

```
{
  "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "script" :{
      "inline" : "ctx._source.username = ctx._source.username;",
      "lang" : "painless"
    }
}
```

This worked for me on es 5.6, above one did not!

Comment: This is a comment to the Val's answer and not an answer itself.