# Copy data of a field in another field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using following technique to copy one field into another in ElasticSearch 7.9.2

```
localhost:9200/your_index/_update_by_query

{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
               "product_name": "iphone 9"
        }
    },
    "script" : "ctx._source.company = ctx._source.make;"
}
```

following error is occurred

```
"type": "Parsing exception"
"reason": "Unknown key for a Start_Object in [Script]"
```

I followed these threads
[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291766/how-to-copy-elasticsearch-field-to-another-field)
[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973401/elasticsearch-copy-one-field-value-to-other-field-for-all-documents)

Comment: Could you share the result of your query? Maybe `company` or `make` is not found under root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code executed successfully.

```
localhost:9200/your_index/_update_by_query

{
    "script" : {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "ctx._source.company = ctx._source.make;"
    },
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
               "product_name": "iphone 9"
        }
    }
}
```